# How can I remove the "bubble/round square" around the icons and the dash icon?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, customization

I know that the texture files for the launcher are in `/use/share/unity/5` but I remember the exact files to "erase". I want to make the icons look like windows 7 icons, with no border around them, as well with the dash home icon. I still want the arrows to the side of the icons to show what application I am using.

Thanks.

[image: I don't want the borders.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are:

- launcher_icon_shadow_62.png
- launcher_icon_back_54.png
- launcher_icon_edge_54.png
- launcher_icon_glow_62.png
- launcher_icon_shine_54.png
- squircle* (all files beginning with 'squircle')